# Scaling a polygon in box2D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

Is there any way to scale polygon in box2D to make it bigger foe example. Or is there any tool online where you can draw a polygon and it returns you vertices.

Regards

Comment: `mc.scaleX`? I'm a little confused as to what you're asking for.

Comment: Oh, my bad... i see it now :D